# Getting basic information (sender, recipient, timestamp) of ALL incoming emails in Exchange

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are implementing a reporting system (.net 4.0, c#) that contains all the sender/recipient/timestamp information for all the emails for all the users. We have the requirement that this application should be able to communicate with Exchange 2007 SP1 and Exchange 2010 servers, thus, using the Exchange Web Service Managed API sounds like the technology that we need.

I can create subscriptions on Inbox/Sent items folders for event types "Created" and "New mail". 
The problem is in case of some incoming emails when a user is using some rule that e.g. moves the message directly to some other folder or deletes it based on some defined rules.

Do you have any advice how to get ALL incoming messages that is sent to the user's email address (and then later distributed wherever the exchange server want to do it). We are not interested in spam emails, but if that is the price to get the required information then we will find a solution to coop with it.

thanks in advance for everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could intercept mails before they are placed in a users mailbox. A Transport agent will give you access to all messages. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012.aspx.

Comment: it can be a bit challenging since the software what we are developing will be installed on our business partners' server. I am not sure how keen they would be about installing some component into their exchange :)

Comment: Another option would be to use the ExchangeService.SubscribeToPushNotificationsOnAllFolders to get notifications about all folders in a users mailbox. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.Subscribetopushnotificationsonallfolders(v=exchg.80).aspx. The same is possible for pull- and streaming notifications.